# Do any Star Trek TV shows (or novels) reveal what happened to the Talosians?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-eu

Nothing I've seen or read seems to deal with the Talosians after Kirk allowed Spock to take Pike to them.  Has anyone else read or seen anything about them since?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The Talosians never appear again in the film or TV canon but they do appear in a variety of Trek Books;

- In the short story "[The Greater Good](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MwQnyFkCIL8C&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=the%20Greater%20Good%20bonanno&source=bl&ots=IGGwp6ieJj&sig=RPKTpPzz7Uv9GPaFQSNotjmIREg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m5A9U-PKFaPo7AbGlYGACQ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=the%20Greater%20Good%20bonanno&f=false)" by Margaret Wander Bonanno, contained in the anthology 'Shards and Shadows' a mirror James T. Kirk returns to Talos IV and ordered that its surface be leveled, annihilating the Talosians for the good of the Empire.
- There's a brief reference to a Talosian ship in the original script for "[Star Trek : Nemesis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0253754/)";

> **B-9 :** *I was in space for a long time. Then a ship belonging to the Talosians picked me up. They asked me where I came from. I told
>   them people called the Pakleds took me from my homeworld. They are
>   fat*

- "[Aftermath](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Aftermath)" mentions the desirability of Talosian Windsingers, a form
  of plant life.
- "[Being Human](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Being_Human)" mentions that Starfleet's General Order 7 still forbids travel to Talos IV on pain of execution.
- "[Burning Desire](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Burning_Dreams)" has a very extensive account of the Talosian homeworld. The story is quite convoluted but the main thrust is that the Talosians use their advanced telepathy to breach the Federation embargo on visiting their world.
- In [Cathedral](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Cathedral), Cadet Nog mentions that he's visited Talos IV. There's no mention of how he avoided being executed for this.

[Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Talosian) also mentions their appearance in the Trek Comic "[Telepathy War](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Telepathy_War)"

> By 2373, the Talosians became active participants in the so-called
>   Telepathy War with the Dominion. Many Talosians were affected by the
>   Meme Virus, as were many telepathic races within the Federation.
>   Several Jem'Hadar invaded Talos IV, but Omega Squad, led by a
>   telepathic recreation of Christopher Pike, helped repel the invasion.

Comment: I was going to mention "Telepathy War." That story-arc also shows that they maintain a low-level telepathic contact in Spock. It also may explain their apparent space-faring nature by *Star Trek: Nemesis*; the Talosians find themselves with some mind-wiped Jem'Hadar, who are just perfect for slave labour, as well as having troop-ships.

Comment: "Cadet Nog mentions that he's visited Talos IV. There's no mention of how he avoided being executed for this." Might this be a reference to Telepathy War? I think Nog was on Omega Squad.

Comment: "Meme virus"?!?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Not that kind of meme; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Meme_virus

Answer (score 0):

Seems they went on to rebuild their society and become a warp-capable culture.

From [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Talosian):

> According to [Star Trek: Star Charts](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_Star_Charts) (p. 34), the Talosians became warp capable 500,000 years prior to 2378.

Comment: This covers them prior to The Menagerie. The question seems to be asking about what happened to them after that episode.